# Windows cursor for mouse cape

Tags: windows, macos, mouse-cursor, osx-yosemite

Do you know if a windows cursor exists for Mousecape. I have looked on google and I have been unable to find any that look like the one on Windows 8/10. If one does not exist could you make one or give instructions how to.
Thanks Thomas

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about Mousecape is that you can import pngs without conversion. Just find any old image of a Windows 8/10 cursor, make it a transparent png with the magic wand tool in preview (or whatever other application; preview is very easy and accessible), and drag the file into a slot in Mousecape.